# How can I beautify JSON inside a document?

Tags: json, latex, code-formatting

I was writing a LaTeX document, using Lyx as a front-end. I did not find a way to correctly format JSON data inside these documents.

How can I beautify or format JSON data inside a Latex document?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I do embed code into lyx mostly as program listings imported from external textfiles. There are numerous options that you could apply to the program listing, from line numbers to word wraps and many more.

Comment: Autoformatting isn't one of those, though. At least `listings` doesn't have the option as the approach to prettifying is rather braindead anyway (just literal/keyword highlighting instead of understanding the grammar).

Comment: I guess I'm missing something here. So, I've used listing to insert the JSON but what am I expecting here because I don't see any significant difference in the generated PDF. I mean, leave alone the keyword highlighting, I don't even see any formatting. Any inputs?

Comment: Never mind. I missed the settings option. I'm playing with it now.

Answer (score 39):

I'm using [minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) package.

First you have to [install and configure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23466/10126) it (do not forget to add [pygmentize.cmd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23732/10126) file on Windows 7). Then you have to add `\usepackage{minted}` to the `LaTeX Preambel` and finally insert following code into `TeX Code` box (for JSON you can use `js` code type):

```
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}[frame=single,
               framesep=3mm,
               linenos=true,
               xleftmargin=21pt,
               tabsize=4]{js}
{     
    "firstName": "John"
    "lastName" : "Smith",
    "age" : 25
}
\end{minted}
\caption{JSON example} 
\label{json-example}
\end{listing}
```

It is not perfect solution, but it works and produce really nice listing:
[image: minted json example]

Comment: There is also the code type `{json}`, producing a slightly different result